# Как связать Points  у Polyline с данными?

Tags: wpf, binding, xaml

Как мне связать свойство в разметке `Points` объекта `Polylinу` с данными из класса?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Вот нашел ответ [тут.](http://bea.stollnitz.com/blog/?s=PointCollection&submit=Search)